# RabbitMQ, PHP, Python

Tags: php, python, linux, rabbitmq

I am stuck and need an advice.

I have a PHP script which generates over 1 million emails per hour. On the current setup, these emails are put into an SSD drive folder and a python script monitors this drive, loops each file and sends them to our local MTA via SMTP protocol. With this setup, I am able to process ~9000 emails per minute. As you can see, there's a huge gap between input and output.

I am considering saving messages to RabbitMQ and then pull those messages from Python workers and then send to local MTA via SMTP.

What do you think? Is this a good setup or do you have any other recommendation/suggestion for such a high-volume activity system?

Thanks for your help

M.

Comment: To me it looks that the biggest problem is to stored. Writing a file is quite costly. RabbitMQ can be an idea, as well as some of these: AWS pools, Celery, Redis.

Comment: So, you say that if I get rid of SSD IO operation and pass emails to RabbitMQ, it will be much faster, right?

Comment: Yes, to me yes. There is no point in writing to a file something that will be "flying". Just make good loggers to trace errors, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I will try RabbitMQ and update this post about my results.

Comment: The speed comes from the fact, that RabbitMQ holds the messages (in this case your emails) in memory. Another advantage is, that you can easily apply as many workers as you want, without worrying about concurrent access etc. I guess it's a great idea and am looking forward for a follow up.